# Any official Russian statement concerning Nord Stream sabotage?

Tags: russian-federation, nord-stream

On October 29, 2022, various European news agencies such as Reuters published [articles claiming that the Russian Ministry of Defense had specifically accused UK special forces of sabotaging the Nord Stream pipeline in September](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-british-navy-personnel-blew-up-nord-stream-gas-pipelines-2022-10-29/). However, these articles merely contained excerpts from the alleged Russian statement.

I could not find any news release or statement of this type on the website of the Russian Ministry of Defense.

Is there any publicly available statement released by the aforesaid Ministry of Defense detailing these new accusations?

Answer (score 7):

No - the Reuters article seems to contain the full detail of the allegations so far. There doesn't appear to be any detail released regarding the substance of these claims. The statement in question was posted on the Russian Ministry of Defence's [Telegram channel](https://t.me/MFARussia/13978):

> Today at 4.20 am, the Kiev regime carried out a terrorist attack against the ships of the Black Sea Fleet and civilian ships that were on the outer and inner roadsteads of the Sevastopol base. The attack involved nine unmanned aerial vehicles and seven autonomous maritime drones.
>
> ❗️ It should be emphasised that the ships of the Black Sea Fleet that were subjected to the terrorist attack are involved in ensuring the security of the ‘grain corridor’ as part of an international initiative to export agricultural products from Ukrainian ports.
>
> The preparation of this terrorist act and the training of military personnel of 73rd Marine Special Operations Center were carried out under supervision of British specialists  in the city of Ochakov, Nikolayev region in Ukraine.
>
> ⚠️ According to the available information, representatives of this unit from the British Navy were involved in plotting, organising, and implementation of the terrorist attack in the Baltic Sea on 26 September this year to blow up the Nord Stream 1 and Nord Stream 2 gas pipelines.

The Russian Foreign Ministry Spokeswoman Maria Zakharova also made a statement on the matter, which is posted on the [Ministry website](https://mid.ru/ru/foreign_policy/news/1835792/) (in Russian):

> The Russian Foreign Ministry, together with the Russian competent departments, is working on practical steps in connection with the involvement of British specialists in the preparation of a terrorist attack in the Black Sea on October 29 and training of the Ukrainian military, as the Russian Ministry of Defense announced.
>
> At the same time, the Russian military reported that they had information about the involvement of the British special services also in a series of explosions on the Nord Stream 1 and Nord Stream 2 gas pipelines in the Baltic Sea. Russia has repeatedly called for a joint investigation into these attacks. Relevant proposals were sent to the governments of Denmark, Sweden and Germany. The fact that the Western countries refused this proposal confirms that they have something to hide. Now we understand what exactly they are hiding.

Answer (score 6):

In his [interview with Tucker Carlson](https://tuckercarlson.com/the-vladimir-putin-interview/), Putin accused the CIA of undermining the Northern Streams. Since Putin is the most official representative of Russia, this can be considered an official statement of Russia.

> Tucker Carlson, journalist: "Who blew up the Nord Streams?
>
> Vladimir Putin, President of the Russian Federation: "You".
>
> Tucker Carlson: "I was busy that day. I did not blow up the Nord
> Stream.
>
> Vladimir Putin, President of the Russian Federation: "You personally
> may have an alibi, but the CIA [CIA] does not have such an alibi."
>
> Tucker Carlson, journalist: "Given that you have evidence and your
> special services, why don't you present such evidence and win this
> propaganda war?"
>
> Vladimir Putin, President of the Russian Federation: "It is very
> difficult to defeat the United States in the propaganda war, because
> the United States controls all the world's media and a lot of European
> ones. The ultimate beneficiary of the largest European media are
> American foundations. Don't you know that?.. Just a moment: we can
> just highlight our sources of information, and we will not achieve
> results. It's already clear to the whole world what happened, and even
> American analysts are talking about it directly. Really?"
>
> Vladimir Putin, President of the Russian Federation: "Why not tell the
> Germans: "Listen, guys, we're giving you money and weapons. Unscrew
> the valve, please, let the gas out of Russia for us. We buy liquefied
> natural gas at exorbitant prices in Europe, which reduces the level of
> our competitiveness and the economy as a whole to zero. Do you want us
> to give you money? Let us live normally, earn money for our economy,
> we give you money from there." No, they don't do that. Why? Ask them.
> (Knocks on the table.) What's here and what's in their heads is the
> same thing."

Answer (score 1):

There is a statement by the head of the Foreign Intelligence Service where he claims to have evidence for the West being responsible. Here is a translation of the part of a [russian article](https://nsn.fm/policy/nakazanie-dlya-evropy-rossiya-obvinila-britaniu-v-podryve-severnyh-potokov?ysclid=l9u6vlxbi5837481181) dealing with that statement and other ones including by Putin:

> Thus, the head of the Foreign Intelligence Service of the Russian
> Federation (SVR), Sergei Naryshkin, claimed that the SVR has documents
> on the "western trace" in the incidents on the Nord Stream and Nord
> Stream-2 gas pipelines.
>
> For her part, Russian Foreign Ministry spokeswoman Maria Zakharova
> said in her Telegram channel that US Secretary of State Anthony
> Blinken, during a joint press conference with Canadian Foreign
> Minister Melanie Joly, openly spoke about the motives of the US and
> NATO for destroying the Nord Stream-1 and Nord Stream-2 pipelines.
>
> She recalled that earlier the head of the White House, Joe Biden,
> declared the readiness of the United States to "end the Nord Stream"
> in the event that Moscow decides to "invade Ukraine." Zakharova
> accompanied her post with a video of this speech by the American
> leader on February 7.
>
> Later, President Vladimir Putin, during an address at the ceremony of
> admission to Russia of the Donetsk, Lugansk People's Republics,
> Zaporozhye and Kherson regions, accused the "Anglo-Saxons" of the
> explosions on the "Northern Streams", calling the incident a
> diversion.
>
> "The Anglo-Saxons have not had enough sanctions. They moved on to
> diversions. Incredibly, but a fact, they organized explosions on
> international gas highways. In fact, they have begun to destroy the
> pan-European energy infrastructure," he said.

Comment: I am not really a Saxon. More like a Scot. Do you think he is including the Scots in that claim?

Comment: They also call Ukrainans "Dills" ("ukrops") that may be worse

Comment: @Stančikas This term is used by ukrainians themselfs and stands for ukro patriots.

Comment: @convert - Ah, so the Russian government was only complimenting Ukrainians for their patriotism! I guess that it why Russia is invading Ukraine: because it has so much respect for it as a country.

Comment: @Obie 2.0 I was just tallking about the meaning of that term. The word patriot is meaned ironically at least by the russians. What the russian really mean by that word I beter will not say to prevent unnecesary discusion. My main point was that it has nothing to do wit dill.

Comment: @Obie 2.0 Also there is a party in Ukraine called UKROP.

Comment: @TylerDurden That term is often?/sometimes? used for the whole English-speaking European-origin populations of Great Britain, North America, Australia and South Africa even though the populations have also Celtic and other origins. "*Anglo-Saxon world, modern societies based on or influenced by English customs*" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_(disambiguation)

Answer (score 1):

As of the time of writing, Reuters [write](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-says-british-navy-personnel-blew-up-nord-stream-gas-pipelines-2022-10-29/) that

- Russia says UK navy personnel blew up pipelines
- Russia does not give evidence for claim
- Britain denies Russian claims
- Russia says will seek UN attention

That much looks official but Russia provides no evidences, even if they say they have something.